# NoModuleFileException: File does not exist for module having uri

Tags: java, intellij-idea, websphere

I am deploying a J2ee project on websphere and I have set up artifacts,ear etc. with intelliJ.
It is a multi module maven project and was working fine till I have accidentally modified some set up in intelliJ.

What can be the reason? What intelliJ setting can influence this?I have tried to investigate pom but they looks fine and I haven not modified them before the issue.

The error is:

```
A file does not exist for module element having uri: namefile.war
```

Comment: Just guessing - but probably your maven war and ear pluging got out of sync with application.xml. Check in target directory generated ear file. Probably your war file have 'snapshot-x.y' in the filename but application.xml expects just war without version.

Comment: @Gas you are right war file has snapshot-x-y in the file name but application.xml expects  just war. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `war` has snapshot change your ear plugin to skip versioning in the file name like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <version>6</version>
                <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```